# How do I populate a NSMutableArray with UILabels?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, ipad, nsmutablearray

I don't think I am creating this array of UILabels correctly.

If I put a breakpoint after this line of code, it shows that the array is empty.

```
 colorLabelArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:  greenLabel, orangeLabel, blackLabel,purpleLabel, yellowLabel, redLabel, blueLabel, whiteLabel, nil];
```

If I do the same thing with UIImages it works just fine.  What am I missing?

Comment: looks strange, are all of your labels not empty

Comment: Yes, that was problem.  Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you *certain* that none of the label objects are nil? Specifically, if `greenLabel` is nil, then `initWithObjects:` will ignore the rest of the argument list and return an empty array.

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is fine. I would check if *greenLabel* is nil?